# DataGridView data

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

I have this class:

```
public class mobileSimple
{
    public DataGridView mobileData { get; set; }

    public DataGridView getMobileData()
    {
        return this.mobileData;
    }

    public void addMobileData(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (mobileData == null)
        {
            this.mobileData = new DataGridView();
        }
        this.mobileData.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

And I have this method in a form:

```
private void getMobileData2()
{
    mobileSimple mobile = null;

    string query = mobileQueryProvider.getMobileSimple();

    sqlConnect connect = new sqlConnect();
    DataTable mobileSimpleDataTable = connect.getBD(query);

    if (mobileSimpleDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        mobile = new mobileSimple();
        mobile.addMobileData(mobileSimpleDataTable);
    }
    gvMobile.DataSource = mobile.getMobileData();
}
```

Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong please? The DataGridView should be filled... I have tested the query and I am getting 2 rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the `query` should return more than 2 rows?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek the query is returning at the moment 2 rows.. but can also return 1 or 1000...

Comment: @Chris I have the load Handle that calls this method...

Comment: @Nuno So when it can return a random number of rows, how could you tell that is it not working?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek It is not working because the current query is returning 2 rows and I don't see them in the DataGridView

Comment: @Nuno Oh, right. Than try debugging your program and maybe you will find out where are your lost data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more of research and I found the answer.

At the end of the method:

```
gvMobile.DataSource = mobile.getMobileData();
```

I was missing:

```
gvMobile.DataSource = mobile.getMobileData().DataSource;
```

Thank you for the help still.